# Why is the image's Hog generation values so low in outdoor scene?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am attempting to find Pedestriants/People in images with the help of a cascade classifier which uses HOG as features.

The problem I'm trying to solve is in the initial stage, feature generation.
Where the HOG values in certain areas of the images are too low and hence the classifier fails.

The images below were captured using a Basler aca640-100gc Camera.
The visualization of the HOG was borrowed from the code in the [webpage](http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/doku.php?id=public%3ahog_descriptor_computation_and_visualization). Code also attached in the end of the question.

This first image here and its HOG is what I'm trying to achieve.
A realistic outdoor scene which can be used to generate features and hopefully find people. This is not what I have captured using my camera.

#### Captured Outdoor Images results

The images below are what I have created with the camera. I have tried all basic variations where I have played with the brightness and Focus But this still yeilds a poor result in an outdoor scene. Where I am inside the car and the camera is attached close to the windscreen.

But on the Contrary when the same camera was used to record indoor scene It works fine. Why it works when its in an indoor situtation and why not in an outdoor scene is something I can't understand.

[image]

[image]

#### Captured Indoor Images results

As seen in the images below same configuration works for an indoor scene.

[image]

[image]

#### Desired results

Ideally I would like results of the out door recordings to look like so.

Could anyone give me insight why this happens?
or How I can over come this issue to generate reliable HOGs for detection?

[image: Reference input image]

[image: HOG of reference image]

### Code to visualize HOG

```
Mat img_raw = imread("C:\\testimg.png", 1); // load as color image

resize(img_raw, img_raw, Size(64,128) );

Mat img;
cvtColor(img_raw, img, CV_RGB2GRAY);


HOGDescriptor d;
// Size(128,64), //winSize
// Size(16,16), //blocksize
// Size(8,8), //blockStride,
// Size(8,8), //cellSize,
// 9, //nbins,
// 0, //derivAper,
// -1, //winSigma,
// 0, //histogramNormType,
// 0.2, //L2HysThresh,
// 0 //gammal correction,
// //nlevels=64
//);
 
// void HOGDescriptor::compute(const Mat& img, vector<float>& descriptors,
//                             Size winStride, Size padding,
//                             const vector<Point>& locations) const
vector<float> descriptorsValues;
vector<Point> locations;
d.compute( img, descriptorsValues, Size(8,8), Size(8,8), locations);
 
cout << "HOG descriptor size is " << d.getDescriptorSize() << endl;
cout << "img dimensions: " << img.cols << " width x " << img.rows << "height" << endl;
cout << "Found " << descriptorsValues.size() << " descriptor values" << endl;
cout << "Nr of locations specified : " << locations.size() << endl;

Mat get_hogdescriptor_visual_image(Mat& origImg,
                                   vector<float>& descriptorValues,
                                   Size winSize,
                                   Size cellSize,                                   
                                   int scaleFactor,
                                   double viz_factor)
{   
    Mat visual_image;
    resize(origImg, visual_image, Size(origImg.cols*scaleFactor, origImg.rows*scaleFactor));
 
    int gradientBinSize = 9;
    // dividing 180° into 9 bins, how large (in rad) is one bin?
    float radRangeForOneBin = 3.14/(float)gradientBinSize; 
 
    // prepare data structure: 9 orientation / gradient strenghts for each cell
    int cells_in_x_dir = winSize.width / cellSize.width;
    int cells_in_y_dir = winSize.height / cellSize.height;
    int totalnrofcells = cells_in_x_dir * cells_in_y_dir;
    float*** gradientStrengths = new float**[cells_in_y_dir];
    int** cellUpdateCounter   = new int*[cells_in_y_dir];
    for (int y=0; y<cells_in_y_dir; y++)
    {
        gradientStrengths[y] = new float*[cells_in_x_dir];
        cellUpdateCounter[y] = new int[cells_in_x_dir];
        for (int x=0; x<cells_in_x_dir; x++)
        {
            gradientStrengths[y][x] = new float[gradientBinSize];
            cellUpdateCounter[y][x] = 0;
 
            for (int bin=0; bin<gradientBinSize; bin++)
                gradientStrengths[y][x][bin] = 0.0;
        }
    }
 
    // nr of blocks = nr of cells - 1
    // since there is a new block on each cell (overlapping blocks!) but the last one
    int blocks_in_x_dir = cells_in_x_dir - 1;
    int blocks_in_y_dir = cells_in_y_dir - 1;
 
    // compute gradient strengths per cell
    int descriptorDataIdx = 0;
    int cellx = 0;
    int celly = 0;
 
    for (int blockx=0; blockx<blocks_in_x_dir; blockx++)
    {
        for (int blocky=0; blocky<blocks_in_y_dir; blocky++)            
        {
            // 4 cells per block ...
            for (int cellNr=0; cellNr<4; cellNr++)
            {
                // compute corresponding cell nr
                int cellx = blockx;
                int celly = blocky;
                if (cellNr==1) celly++;
                if (cellNr==2) cellx++;
                if (cellNr==3)
                {
                    cellx++;
                    celly++;
                }
 
                for (int bin=0; bin<gradientBinSize; bin++)
                {
                    float gradientStrength = descriptorValues[ descriptorDataIdx ];
                    descriptorDataIdx++;
 
                    gradientStrengths[celly][cellx][bin] += gradientStrength;
 
                } // for (all bins)
 
 
                // note: overlapping blocks lead to multiple updates of this sum!
                // we therefore keep track how often a cell was updated,
                // to compute average gradient strengths
                cellUpdateCounter[celly][cellx]++;
 
            } // for (all cells)
 
 
        } // for (all block x pos)
    } // for (all block y pos)
 
 
    // compute average gradient strengths
    for (int celly=0; celly<cells_in_y_dir; celly++)
    {
        for (int cellx=0; cellx<cells_in_x_dir; cellx++)
        {
 
            float NrUpdatesForThisCell = (float)cellUpdateCounter[celly][cellx];
 
            // compute average gradient strenghts for each gradient bin direction
            for (int bin=0; bin<gradientBinSize; bin++)
            {
                gradientStrengths[celly][cellx][bin] /= NrUpdatesForThisCell;
            }
        }
    }
 
 
    cout << "descriptorDataIdx = " << descriptorDataIdx << endl;
 
    // draw cells
    for (int celly=0; celly<cells_in_y_dir; celly++)
    {
        for (int cellx=0; cellx<cells_in_x_dir; cellx++)
        {
            int drawX = cellx * cellSize.width;
            int drawY = celly * cellSize.height;
 
            int mx = drawX + cellSize.width/2;
            int my = drawY + cellSize.height/2;
 
            rectangle(visual_image,
                      Point(drawX*scaleFactor,drawY*scaleFactor),
                      Point((drawX+cellSize.width)*scaleFactor,
                      (drawY+cellSize.height)*scaleFactor),
                      CV_RGB(100,100,100),
                      1);
 
            // draw in each cell all 9 gradient strengths
            for (int bin=0; bin<gradientBinSize; bin++)
            {
                float currentGradStrength = gradientStrengths[celly][cellx][bin];
 
                // no line to draw?
                if (currentGradStrength==0)
                    continue;
 
                float currRad = bin * radRangeForOneBin + radRangeForOneBin/2;
 
                float dirVecX = cos( currRad );
                float dirVecY = sin( currRad );
                float maxVecLen = cellSize.width/2;
                float scale = viz_factor; // just a visual_imagealization scale,
                                          // to see the lines better
 
                // compute line coordinates
                float x1 = mx - dirVecX * currentGradStrength * maxVecLen * scale;
                float y1 = my - dirVecY * currentGradStrength * maxVecLen * scale;
                float x2 = mx + dirVecX * currentGradStrength * maxVecLen * scale;
                float y2 = my + dirVecY * currentGradStrength * maxVecLen * scale;
 
                // draw gradient visual_imagealization
                line(visual_image,
                     Point(x1*scaleFactor,y1*scaleFactor),
                     Point(x2*scaleFactor,y2*scaleFactor),
                     CV_RGB(0,0,255),
                     1);
 
            } // for (all bins)
 
        } // for (cellx)
    } // for (celly)
 
 
    // don't forget to free memory allocated by helper data structures!
    for (int y=0; y<cells_in_y_dir; y++)
    {
      for (int x=0; x<cells_in_x_dir; x++)
      {
           delete[] gradientStrengths[y][x];            
      }
      delete[] gradientStrengths[y];
      delete[] cellUpdateCounter[y];
    }
    delete[] gradientStrengths;
    delete[] cellUpdateCounter;
 
    return visual_image;
 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried an outdoor scene with people the same size as in your indoor scene? The first outdoor scene is quite tough to see the person on the right, in the shadows. I suggest you start with easier outdoor images.

Comment: @cdmh I get your point about the pedestrians being too small. But I have a little sucesses by using another dataset to detect people where, I was told the camera was in the car for [example](http://i.imgur.com/SXcsYCh.png). The problem I have for now is the weak HOG results even though edges are present witin the cell.